# Issue with FB C# SDK Get method, it works with static string but not with an string formed with variables

Tags: facebook, string, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm working with FB C# SDK. Probably my question is very basic but I have already tried tons of options and I can't solve my problem.

I'm using the get method to retrieve info from facebook, it works perfectly with albums, so it isn't a problem of access_token or initialization.

This is the line of code that I use and it returns me the object with the information of albums, for any user it will be always the same since the app asks for all his albums. It works fine:

```
    dynamic fotos = client.Get("me/albums");
```

The problem comes when I ask for photos, because it's nos an static value like with albums, it's a value based on user selection, so, I use a variable instead:

```
    public ActionResult Photos(string albumstring)
           { 
           ... more code asking for token, etc. 

    dynamic fotos = client.Get(albumstring);
```

There it fails and it returns me an empty object. The string text at albumstring is exactly the one needed: "10150240194251714/photos" but it just don't work.

I tested it staticly like this, and it works!:

```
     public ActionResult Photos(string albumstring)
           { 
           ... more code asking for token, etc. 

    albumstring2 = "10150240194251714/photos"; 

    dynamic fotos = client.Get(albumstring2);
```

But it only works if it's an static value, mixing it with a variable makes it fail, like in this example:

```
     public ActionResult Photos(string albumId)
           { 
           ... more code asking for token, etc. 

    albumstring = albumId + "/photos"; 

    dynamic fotos = client.Get(albumstring);
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to construct the string like StringBuilders, adding the escape char \, contructing it from the view and bringing it complete to the controller, etc. But it seems that if the string is not directly written it just won't work.

Probably it's an error from the fb c#sdk, but I need to workaround it and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

this is the method I use and it works fine to retrieve some album photosm where the class AlbumPhoto is just a DTO to capture de data. I hope it helps

```
public static List<AlbumPhoto> GetAlbumPhotos(string userAccessToken, string albumId)
    {
        var list = new List<AlbumPhoto>();
        var client = new FacebookClient(userAccessToken);

        dynamic photos = client.Get(String.Format("/{0}/photos", albumId));
        foreach (var photo in photos.data)
        {
            lista.Add(new AlbumPhoto
            {
                FacebookId = photo.id,
                Name = photo.name,
                ImageUrl = photo.source,
                Height = (int)photo.height,
                Width = (int)photo.width
            });
        }
        return list;
    }
```